# Difference between PowerShell 5.1 and 7 when working with certificates

Tags: .net, powershell, .net-core, assemblies, powershell-core

Below is a small sample of the script that I am making. I need it to work in PowerShell 5.1
At the moment it only works in PS7. I installed the package "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 7.0.3" and copied the dll's I am referencing in the script folder.
When I run this script in PS7 I get ouput from "new-object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SigningCredentials($x509cert)"
On PS5.1 I get the error:

```
System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "The type initializer for 'PerTypeValues`1' threw an exception." ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'PerTypeValues`1' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at System.SpanHelpers.PerTypeValues`1.MeasureArrayAdjustment()
   at System.SpanHelpers.PerTypeValues`1..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(Byte[] inArray, Int32 offset, Int32 length)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityKey..ctor(X509Certificate2 certificate)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials..ctor(X509Certificate2 certificate)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SigningCredentials..ctor(X509Certificate2 certificate)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.DotNetAdapter.AuxiliaryConstructorInvoke(MethodInformation methodInformation, Object[] arguments, Object[] originalArguments)
   at System.Management.Automation.DotNetAdapter.ConstructorInvokeDotNet(Type type, ConstructorInfo[] constructors, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand.CallConstructor(Type type, ConstructorInfo[] constructors, Object[] args)
```

Can someone explain to me what the difference is between 5.1 and 7 other than .NET version? And why this piece of code won't run on 5.1?

```
$CertPassWord       = "password" # Password used for creating the certificate
$CertificatePath_Pfx = "C:\Temp\Certs\test.pfx" # Path where the certificate is saved 
 

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Temp\Certs\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.dll")


$x509cert = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($CertificatePath_Pfx, $CertPassWord)
new-object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SigningCredentials($x509cert)
```

Comment: Which version of .Net are the libraries installed at C:\Temp\Certs\ intended for? You might have the best luck if you choose the .Net Standard 2.0 libraries. However, the JSON parsers are significantly different between .Net 6+ and .Net Framework. There's a reason everyone used to use Newtonsoft.Json before .Net 6.

Comment: Those are .NET framework 4.8 dll's and are used to create the SignedCredential object. Not all dll's are needed for this example. I removed the dll's that are not needed for the example

Comment: I don't know what the implications are, but note that the [`Microsoft.IdentityModel`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel) NuGet package is .NET Framework-only, whereas [`System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt) is a cross-edition package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem why it wasn't running in PS 5.1. I updated my question with the detailed exception. The dll "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll" wasn't loaded in PowerShell session causing the script to fail. In PS 7 this dll is loaded by default. I only had a newer version then was expected so I needed a binding redirect in PowerShell 5.1. I got the way to do that from this question: [Powershell config assembly redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24181557/powershell-config-assembly-redirect)

This is my example script that is working in PS 5.1

```
$CertPassWord       = "password" # Password used for creating the certificate
$CertificatePath_Pfx = "C:\Temp\Certs\test.pfx" # Path where the certificate is saved 
 

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Temp\Certs\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.dll")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Temp\Certs\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll")



$OnAssemblyResolve = [System.ResolveEventHandler] {
    param($sender, $e)

    $searchFor = $null
    if ($e.Name -match "(.*?), .*") {
        $searchFor = $matches[1]
    }
    foreach ($a in [System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()) {
        Write-Host $a
        $foundItem = $null
        if ($a.FullName -match "(.*?), .*") {
            $foundItem = $matches[1]
        }
    
        if ($foundItem -eq $searchFor) {
            return $a
        }
    }
    return $null
}
[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.add_AssemblyResolve($OnAssemblyResolve)

try {
$x509cert = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($CertificatePath_Pfx, $CertPassWord)
new-object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SigningCredentials($x509cert)
}

catch {
     Write-Host "An error occurred:"
  Write-Host $_.Exception
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Platform Compatibility...

PowerShell 5.1:

It is the version of PowerShell that is built into Windows and is available on all Windows systems (starting from Windows 7). It primarily targets Windows environments.

PowerShell 7:

This is cross-platform and can run on Windows, Linux, and macOS. It extends PowerShell's reach beyond just Windows systems, making it more versatile for cross-platform scripting and automation.

.NET Version...

PowerShell 5.1:

It relies on the .NET Framework, which is a Windows-only technology. It uses the .NET Framework 4.5.

PowerShell 7:

This is built on the .NET Core (now known as .NET 5+), which is cross-platform. It benefits from the improved performance and cross-platform compatibility of .NET Core.

Compatibility with Modules...

PowerShell 5.1:

It supports a wide range of Windows-specific modules and cmdlets. Some modules and cmdlets may not work in cross-platform scenarios.

PowerShell 7:

While it maintains compatibility with many modules designed for PowerShell 5.1, it also offers new features and improvements. It's more compatible with cross-platform modules and cmdlets, making it suitable for multi-platform scripting.

Language Features and Improvements...

PowerShell 5.1:

It has the features and improvements available up to that version, but development and enhancements are primarily focused on Windows.

PowerShell 7:

It introduces new language features and improvements, as well as bug fixes. While maintaining backward compatibility, it also adds support for modern scripting practices and cross-platform capabilities.

PowerShell Gallery...

PowerShell 5.1:

It uses the PowerShell Gallery to distribute modules and scripts primarily for Windows environments.

PowerShell 7:

It continues to use the PowerShell Gallery but provides a broader range of modules and scripts that can be used across different platforms.

Community and Open Source...

PowerShell 5.1:

Developed and maintained by Microsoft, it follows a traditional closed-source development model.

PowerShell 7:

It is an open-source project hosted on GitHub. The community actively contributes to its development, and it benefits from input and contributions from a wider range of users.

So... PowerShell 5.1 is the traditional Windows-centric version, while PowerShell 7 is the cross-platform, open-source successor that brings many improvements and the ability to work on multiple operating systems.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. This explains a lot. Do you any idea why this code runs on 7 but not on 5.1?

Comment: The code you provided is using the Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens assembly, which might have better compatibility with .NET Core (PowerShell 7) than with the .NET Framework (PowerShell 5.1). This could explain why the code runs successfully in PowerShell 7 but not in PowerShell 5.1.

Comment: If you need to run this code in PowerShell 5.1 and are experiencing issues, you might consider checking if there are updates or additional libraries or assemblies that need to be installed or loaded to make it work in that environment. Additionally, upgrading to PowerShell 7 or a more recent version of .NET Framework might provide better compatibility for this type of code.